# CSS – Image width

Tags: css, image, width

i have a problem on the width of an image on my website. I want it to be 100%, so that the image has the full width of the browser frame. But currently it is only 1000px wide. Please check:

http://www.injuvik.de/Live/

I am talking about the image on top of the page.

How can i fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the existing `max-width` style that's limiting the `width`.

```
img {
  max-width:1000px;
}
```